# Python/Kivy passing variables

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

Struggling to pass a variable to kivy window. I have read similar threads all over the place but none of the fixes seem to work for me. Im sure this is simple to someone who knows their way around tiny, unfortunately I don't.

main.py

```
import kivy
from kivy.uix.togglebutton import ToggleButton
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.app import App
kivy.require('1.10.0')
from phue import Bridge
import nest
b = Bridge('xxx.xxx.x.xxx')
b.connect()
b.get_api()
lights = b.lights

class Controller(GridLayout):

    print("launching")


    def __init__(self):
            super(Controller, self).__init__()

    def KitchenSpot1(self,state):
        lights[0].name
        lights[0].on = state

    def update(dt):
        if b.get_light(1, 'on')== True:
            #print("down") # When this line is commented out I get an continuous accurate update on the status of the light, showing that its working.
            return 'down' # This is the part I want passed to the state criteria in the ivy window
        else:
            #print("up")# When this line is commented out I get an continuous accurate update on the status of the light, showing that its working.
            return 'down' # This is the part I want passed to the state criteria in the ivy window



class ActionApp(App):

    def build(self):

        Clock.schedule_interval(Controller.update, 1.0 / 60.0)
        return Controller()

myApp = ActionApp()
myApp.run()
```

action.kv

```
<Controller>:
    cols: 4
    rows: 3
    spacing: 10

    ToggleButton:
        id: KitchenSpot1Toggle
        text: "Kitchen Spot 1"
        on_press: root.KitchenSpot1(True) 

        #on_release: root.KitchenSpot1(False)
        #state1 = app.update.h
        state: Controller.update # This is the part that is throwing up the error.
```

The error:

```
      11:        #on_release: root.KitchenSpot1(False)
      12:        #state1 = app.update.h
 >>   13:        state: Controller.update
      14:
      15:
...
 NameError: name 'Controller' is not defined
```

Thanks in advance to anyone that can help me.

Comment: have you tried root.update instead of Controller.update?

Answer (score 1):

Make `update` an instance method and use a `StringProperty` to update `state` property in your kv:

**main.py:**

```
import kivy
kivy.require('1.10.0')
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.togglebutton import ToggleButton
from phue import Bridge
import nest



b = Bridge('xxx.xxx.x.xxx')
b.connect()
b.get_api()
lights = b.lights


class Controller(GridLayout):
    state = StringProperty('normal')                        # <<<<<<<<<<<<

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Controller, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.update, 1.0 / 60.0)

    def KitchenSpot1(self,state):
        lights[0].name
        lights[0].on = state

    def update(self, dt):
        if b.get_light(1, 'on'):
            self.state = 'down'                           # <<<<<<<<<<<<
        else:
            self.state = 'normal'                         # <<<<<<<<<<<<


class ActionApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Controller()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    myApp = ActionApp()
    myApp.run()
```

**action.kv:**

```
<Controller>:
    cols: 4
    rows: 3
    spacing: 10
    state: "normal"                                      # <<<<<<<<<<<<

    ToggleButton:
        id: KitchenSpot1Toggle
        text: "Kitchen Spot 1"
        on_press: root.KitchenSpot1(True)

        #on_release: root.KitchenSpot1(False)
        #state1 = app.update.h
        state: root.state                                # <<<<<<<<<<<<
```

Comment: When I copy your code this error is thrown up:     

     Traceback (most recent call last):
       File "main1.py", line 17, in <module>
         class Controller(GridLayout):
       File "main1.py", line 18, in Controller
         state = StringProperty('down')
     NameError: name 'StringProperty' is not defined
    Js-iMac:Python Programs johngoodwin$

Comment: can't format a comment apparently. error: 'StringProperty' is not defined

Comment: Check my imports, you must import `StringProperty`: `from kivy.properties import StringProperty`

Comment: You are a magician! By putting root.state do I jump back to to the controller class?

Comment: Do you know how I would go about getting the button to set root.KitchenSpot1(False) when the button un toggled?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a more generic simplified answer from the [kivy documentation](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.properties.html), look for the section called "Keyword arguments and **init**()" because there are some other ways to do it as well.

The following code passes myvar to the build() method of MyApp. It does this by over-riding the **init**() of the Kivy App class by a new **init**() that calls App.**init**() and then continues with whatever extra initialisation you want. You can then store variables in the MyApp class instances and use them in build().

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label

myvar = 'Hello Kivy'

class MyApp(App):

    def __init__(self, myvar, **kwargs):
        super(MyApp, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.myvar = myvar

    def build(self):
        widget = Label(text=self.myvar)
        return widget

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp(myvar).run()
```